# How can I automatically close files/tabs in sublime text 2 or 3 from the previous branch on git checkout of new branch?

Tags: git, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

How can I automatically close files/tabs in sublime text 2 or 3 from the previous branch on git checkout of new branch? I couldn't find any plugins for this. I have tried sublimegit, git,savvygit plugins. But whenever I change branch or checkout a new branch, the files (tabs) that don't exist in the new branch remain open and marked unsaved. I find this a little confusing. Any solutions?

Comment: All you need to do is close the tabs and select "Close without saving" or whatever dialog pops up. It theoretically should be possible to write a plugin to do this, but it would be a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 4):

The solution could be to write a plugin, which closes the views for which the corresponding file does not exists. This does not interact with svn or gut, but should have your desired behavior in the most cases. *However be careful, that you don't have text only in ST without saving it in a file.* Press `Tools >> Developer >> New Plugin...` and paste:

```py
import os
import sublime_plugin


class CloseUnsavedFilesCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        window = self.window
        for v in window.views():
            file_name = v.file_name()
            if file_name and not os.path.exists(file_name):
                print("Close: '{0}'".format(file_name))
                v.set_scratch(True)
                window.focus_view(v)
                window.run_command("close")
```

Now open the console `` ctrl+` `` and write `window.run_command("close_unsaved_files")` or create a keybinding for `close_unsaved_files`.

Comment: Nice job, have a +1. I was getting all hung up on interacting with git. I planned to get the current branch, watch for a branch change, then compare the contents of the view to the corresponding file in the other branch. If they were the same, I'd close the file in a similar manner to what you did. If they were different, I'd switch back momentarily, pop up a dialog asking the user if they wanted to save it to the old or new branch, then do what they asked. Waaay too complicated :)

Comment: Nice try @r-stein, But three observations:
Small error: The command to run should be `window.run_command("close")`
It closes only one unsaved file at a time not all. Even in a small project one is likely to have several files in one branch that don't exist in another, having to close them one by one defeats the purpose of the plugin, might as well close them manually.
It closes the file that is saved or exists in the directory too.
**Conclusion: This plugin closes only the file/tab that is active in the window whether it is saved or unsaved.**
But thanks anyway. Btw i use sublime text 3.

Comment: @user3172852 the `close_unsaved_files` command is created by this plugin to close the unsaved files, which have a file name. The `close` command is build-in to close the current active view. Hence you should in fact run `window.run_command("close_unsaved_files")`. If you run a different command you obviously have a different behavior.

Comment: Ok, I should have mentioned that I did exactly that (run window.run_command("close_unsaved_files") ) the very first time, and it didn't work. Here is what i did. Opened sublime text 3, > tools > developer > new plugin
I deleted the default/example code in the file and pasted your code.
I saved the file as close_tabs.py in packages directory.
I restarted sublime text 3
I created a new file, entered some text but didn't save it.
I then pressed ctrl + ` and entered the command window.run_command("close_unsaved_files")
The unsaved file doesn't close. Nothing happened.
Then tried "close" cmd

Comment: @user3172852 You should save the file in the `Packages/User` directory (this should be selected by default).

Comment: @r-stein Moved the file to Packages/User, restarted sublime text 3, No luck!

Comment: @user3172852 Opening and saving the file in ST is sufficient. If you look at the console while saving it might show errors or additional information.

Comment: Thanks @r-stein for taking the time out. Your plugin simply failed to work.

Comment: It did work for me, even without restart. I also thought it doesn't , but you have to look at the "reloading plugin" stuff in the console: I had my own syntax error.